# ¿Como devuelvo la respuesta textarea correcta de una pregunta php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, formularios

Estoy intentando crear un formulario de preguntas desde mysql que se responde de manera manual en un textarea, la selección en PHP la obtengo de manera aleatoria, cuando envío el formulario veo las preguntas que se cuestionaron, pero las respuesta me queda siempre la misma, es como si el array lo estuviera utilizando mal:

```
<?php
$conexion = new mysqli('localhost','root','pass','db');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    foreach($_POST['id'] as $id){
            $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM preguntas WHERE id = '$id'");
            while($campo = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){
                echo '<h3>'.$campo['pregunta'].'</h3>';
                echo $_POST['respuesta'];
            }
        }
    } else {
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="">
    <?php
    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM preguntas ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3");
    while($campo = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $campo['id']; ?>">
        <?php echo $campo['pregunta']; ?>
        <br>
        <textarea name="respuesta" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        <hr>
    
    <?php
    }
    ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Si pones `name="id[]"` ¿no deberías poner también `name="respuesta[]"`?

Comment: Si, eso estoy probando, el problema es que al devolver `echo $_POST['respuesta'];` el resultado en cada respuesta es "Array"

Comment: En ese lugar intenté hacer esto `$res = $_POST['res'];for($i=0; $i<=$res; $i++){echo $res[$i];}` pero algo está mal, porque tarda mucho en devolver y solo me da los resultados, es como si anulara el foreach al comienzo

Comment: Tendrías que basarte en el índice: `foreach($_POST['id'] as $i => $id){` y dentro del ciclo `echo $_POST['respuesta'][$i]`

Comment: Súper @Sal muchas gracias!, no sabía bien para que se usaba y todavía no entiendo bien ese elemento en el foreach pero quedó perfecto, muchas gracias!